# El elemento de enlace tiene un tipo 'any' implícito

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Estoy trabajando con ionic y me muestra el error:

El elemento de enlace 'email' tiene un tipo 'any' implícito

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthServiceService {

  constructor(private auth: Auth) { }

  async register({ email, password }) {
    try {
      const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        this.auth,
        email,
        password)
      return user
    } catch (e) {
      return null
    }

  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como solucionarlo

He intentado colocar el tipo de dato en cada objeto pero se presenta el siguiente error

```
async register({ email: string, password: string }) {
    try {
      const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        this.auth,
        email,
        password)
      return user
    } catch (e) {
      return null
    }

  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor coloca el código como texto y no como imagen. Haz clic en [edit] para hacer los cambios necesarios. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, en tu función llamada `register` te falta declarar el tipo de dato de cada clave del objeto que pasas como argumento. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias por la ayuda sin embargo ya intenté agregar el tipo de dato pero sigo con el problema

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ NO, `String` es un Objeto Global, no es un tipo de dato.

Comment: @MauricioContreras sese ta bien ya se lo que es mala mia mala mia

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que no estás declarando correctamente los tipos de datos esperados en el método llamado `asyncRegister`.

Cuando haces esto:

```js
async register({ email, password }) { ... }
```

falta el tipo de dato para `email` y para `password`.

Cuando haces esto:

```js
async register({ email: string, password: string }) { ... }
```

estás declarando incorrectamente el tipo de dato.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Es común cometer este tipo de errores cuando estamos aprendiendo Typescript.

Para declarar el tipo de dato recibido por tu función tienes varias opciones, trataré de mostrarte algunas.

Declarar un tipo de dato que será usado como argumento de tu función:

```js
declare type UserAuthData = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

async register(userData: UserAuthData): Promise<User | null> {
  try {
    const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      this.auth,
      userData.email,
      userData.password
    );
    return user
  } catch (e) {
    if(e instanceof Error) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Si no deseas declarar un tipo de dato, entonces debes declarar el tipo de dato de la siguiente forma:

```
async register(userData: {email: string, password: string}): Promise<User | null> {
  try {
    const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      this.auth,
      userData.email,
      userData.password
    );
    return user
  } catch (e) {
    if(e instanceof Error) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

También podrías usar argumentos independientes en tu función:

```js
async register(email: string, password: string): Promise<User | null> {
  try {
    const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      this.auth,
      email,
      password
    );
    return user
  } catch (e) {
    if(e instanceof Error) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

En caso de que desees usar un objeto literal, como lo tienes en tu código original, también lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```js
async register({email, password}: {email: string, password: string}): Promise<User | null> {
  try {
    const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      this.auth,
      email,
      password
    );
    return user
  } catch (e) {
    if(e instanceof Error) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Puedes observar que he añadido el tipo de "return" devuelto por la función, ya que siempre debes declararlo. Como la función es de tipo `async`, el resultado será una Promesa, por lo cual el tipo de dato devuelto es:

```js
Promise<User | null>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema